# How to create month table in powerquery (M)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to create a month/year table on power query (M). It seems that has no easy way to do that. Here is the code I created to reach that goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its unclear exactly what you are looking for but

```
let Years =  Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.FromRecords({[Years = {1980..2020}]}), "Years"),
#"Add Months" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.AddColumn(Years, "Months", each {1..12}), "Months"),
#"Add Month Names" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Months", "MonthName", each Date.MonthName(#datetime([Years], [Months], 1,0,0,0)))
in #"Add Month Names"
```

generates a table like this, and you can change the start/ending year in the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. If anybody could find a easier and more elegant solution, it will be welcomed.

To use this code, create a blanked query, go to ***Advanced Editor*** and replace the existing code for this one.

```
let
    first_date = #date(2020, 1, 1),
    last_day = DateTime.LocalNow(),
    num_months = ((Date.Year(last_day) - Date.Year(first_date)) * 12 + Date.Month(last_day) - Date.Month(first_date)),
    list_of_num = List.Numbers(0, num_months, 1),
    table_from_list = Table.FromValue(list_of_num, [DefaultColumnName = "Index"]),
    add_col_year = Table.AddColumn(table_from_list, "Year", each Date.Year(Date.AddMonths(first_date, [Index])), Int64.Type),
    add_col_month = Table.AddColumn(add_col_year, "Mes", each Date.Month(Date.AddMonths(first_date, [Index])), Int64.Type)
in
    add_col_month
```